# Assign some indices of a list to a new list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, assign

I want to assign some indices of a list with shape of `1000*1` to another list. The values of `h_sr1`, `h_r1d`, `h_sr2` and `h_r2d` are real + imaginary with shape of `(1000,1)`, but when I try to assign these values to new variables `h_s` and `h_r`, the values of `(h_sr1, h_r1d, h_sr2, h_r2d)` don't properly assign to the new variable `(h_s, h_r)`. Can you give me any idea where I am making a mistake?

```
for n in range(1000):
        if R_1[n,0] > R_2[n,0]:
            h_s[n,0] = h_sr1[n,0]
            h_r[n,0] = h_r1d[n,0]
        else:
            h_s[n,0] = h_sr2[n,0]
            h_r[n,0] = h_r2d[n,0]
```

Comment: How did you initialize `h_s` and `h_r`? The problem is most likely there. Also, it looks like you should use `numpy`.

Comment: "a list with shape" lists do not have a shape. Do you mean a ``numpy.array``?

Comment: np.empty((1000,1), dtype=float) like this. I have noticed that I used int instead of float but I edited it to float. It still doesn't include the imaginer part of the value. I also removed *dtype = float* from the assignment but  h_s and h_r still do not include the imaginer part of the value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have changed data type to complex and it is working now.